# Typescript: trying to infer the value of a key-value pair type - Discord.js dynamic events

Tags: typescript, discord, discord.js, type-inference, typing

I'm building a discord.js bot with Typescript and implementing dynamic events (with correct dynamic typing) seems to be a bit of a challenge.

In my main file `index.ts` I have the following code, which follows the guidelines of discord.js their docs:

```js
    const eventFiles = fs
      .readdirSync("./events")
      .filter((file) => file.endsWith(".ts"));

    eventFiles.forEach(async (file) => {
      const event: IBotEvent = await import(`./events/${file}`);
      if (event.once) {
        this.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
      } else {
        this.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
      }
    });
```

Where `event.name` is a key from `ClientEvents` and `...args` is an unknown amount of parameters with an unknown type (the amount of params and their types differs for every event `ClientEvent`).

For reference, a small portion of the `ClientEvents` interface from Discord looks like this:

```js
export interface ClientEvents {
  // ...
  emojiUpdate: [oldEmoji: GuildEmoji, newEmoji: GuildEmoji];
  messageCreate: [message: Message];
  ready: [client: Client<true>];
  interactionCreate: [interaction: Interaction];
  // ...
}
```

In the `index.ts`, when `event.name` would be "ready", you'd expect to receive the `client` parameter of type `Client<true>` in the `event.execute` parameter down the line.

In my event file(s) I do the following:

```js
import { ClientEvents } from "discord.js";
import { IBotEvent } from "../interfaces";

export default class ReadyEvent implements IBotEvent {
  name: keyof ClientEvents; // name is a string key that exists in ClientEvents

  once: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.name = "ready";
    this.once = true;
  }

  // This works but it is NOT dynamic
  // You never know which parameter(s) exists here - it's different for each event type
  // In this case I have the "ready" event, so we only get 1 parameter, which is the Client
  // You'd have to go into the ClientEvents interface and copy/paste the parameters
  public execute = async (client: Client): Promise<void> => {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  };
}
```

What I am trying to do is to always have the correct dynamically typed parameters inside my event class.

I have tried this solution, but it doesn't work in all cases (only when you have 1 parameter) and you have to manually edit the key string for every event class you implement:

```js
  public execute = async (client: ClientEvents["ready"][0]): Promise<void> => {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  };
```

NOTE* I am aware that the issue isn't huge and I have a semi-working example (where some manual editing is still required for each new event class). But I'm posting this to make development even more effortless and to improve/learn/understand Typescript better.